# ng click update model not resetting ng src

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng repeat which will display four images.
On click on any one of these, I have to change the image of the particular one and reset other to its previous image. My angularJs code goes like this

```
<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 noPaddingLeftRight' ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
    <img ng-click="selectedCategory = category.Category_Id; selectedNo = category.RunningNumber;" ng-src="{{$index == selectedNo?category.HoverImageName:category.CategoryImage}}" alt='home' style='align-content: center; margin-top: 10px;' />
</div>
```

after I click it will change the particular one but it won't reset the previous image.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you try removing {{}} from ng-src?

Comment: image path directly goes like this /$index%20==%20selectedNo?category.HoverImageName:category.CategoryImage

Comment: I'll suggest you to call a method from ng-click. place one variable for ng-src and write code to decide the url in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making way harder than necessary. Why do you need two variables to remember which category is selected? Why do you set the `selectedNo` to `category.RunningNumber`, but then comparing it with `$index`. If it's supposed to be an index, then set it to the index. If it's supposed to be the running number of the category, then compare it with the runing number.

Also, you're modifying a variable of the scope, but ng-repeat has its own scope. So each iteration has its own selectedCategory and selectedNo.

So, create an object in your controller:

```
$scope.model = {
  selectedCategory: null
};
```

And then all you need is

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
    <img ng-click="model.selectedCategory = category" 
         ng-src="{{ model.selectedCategory == category ? category.HoverImageName : category.CategoryImage }}" />
</div>
```

Or delegate to a function:

```
$scope.selectedCategory = null;
$scope.selectCategory = function(category) {
  $scope.selectedCategory = category;
};

<div ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
    <img ng-click="selectCategory(category)" 
         ng-src="{{ selectedCategory == category ? category.HoverImageName : category.CategoryImage }}" />
</div>
```

Comment: excellent. it worked. i did,t realized that ng-repeat will have its own scope. Thanx.